# Which values for a link-tag's rel-attribute should be used to represent a hierarchy of collections and documents?

Tags: html, rest, web

I would like to represent links to subfolders and documents in a folder in hypertext documents (possibly using [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html)). Therefore, a document representing a folder should have links to the parent folder, subfolders and files contained in the folder.
For the parent folder, <link rel="up" href=".." > seems to be the straightforward choice. However, I am unsure as to what is most appropriate for links to subfolders and documents contained in the folder.
There are a couple of options defined in [RFC-5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988). However, I couldn't say which one would be most appropriate to represent a tree of folders and files.

I could come up with my own values and produce documents. For example (using HTML syntax rather then HAL for familiarity):

```
...
<link rel="self" href="http://example.com/some/folder/">
<link rel="up" href="http://example.com/some/">
<link rel="file" href="image1.jpg">
<link rel="file" href="image2.png">
<link rel="folder" href="subfolder/">
...
```

Using custom rel-attributes has the clear disadvantage of applications consuming these documents needing to have explicit support for them. Consequently, I'd rather use something that an application could understand by just following standards and best practices.

Update:
AtomPub (RFC 5023) )seems to use rel="edit" on links to members of a collection. They don't have a concept for sub.collection I believe. rel="subsection" from RFC-5988 might be an option.

Comment: The `rel` attribute is designed to express the *semantic* relationship between documents, not their organisation on a filesystem. If none of the existing values are applicable, just don't use any. The attribute isn't mandatory.

Comment: I would argue, that the semantic relationship of something being an item in a collection or something being a sub-collection, possibly containing more items is a relationship worth expressing in a hypertext application.

Comment: So far, using "subsection" for subcollections and "item" for documents seem like a reasonable approach... any thoughts?

Comment: This might possibly be better suited for [webmasters.se](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) (assuming SEO relation).

Comment: No SEO relation. This is for the design of a RESTful web service using HAL

Comment: List of accepted / defined rel values as per HTML references: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types

Answer (score 3):

**Representing a Hierarchy**
One very common way to represent a hierarchy is to use the concept of parent-child relationships between levels in the hierarchy. This allows you to describe the hierarchy very generally without tying yourself to *only* representing folders and documents since parent-child/children can represent *any* hierarchy. DOM parsers, for example, use this concept heavily, since the DOM is a hierarchy.

Assuming your hierarchy is not fully balanced (ie. you can have documents at 3 levels deep, and also at 20 levels deep), you need to know what type of "node" you are at, either a collection (folder) or a leaf (document). With the notion of collection vs. leaf, and parent vs. child/children, you will be able to easily notate the relationship of all the links you should need.

**Content Type**
The most important part of any REST interaction is the clear definition of the content types at both the client and the server. Content types are rather obscure as far as what they need to actually be, but for your purposes it could be as little as indicating that the general resource "format" is HAL, and would also define the meaning of the `parent` and `child` rel values.

Most people forget that content types are for *humans*. Only the *names* of the content types matter to user-agents, not the contents of the content type definition. The content type definitions are used by developers (or *very* smart user agents) to decide how to interpret things. The user-agent just uses the name to switch interpretation modes.

**Standards are not Everything**
In general, it's more important for your application to represent *it's own* resources the way *your application* needs to than for you to try to shoehorn your representation(s) into some "standard". If it makes the most sense for your application to use `up`, `folder`, and `file`, the by all means use those link relations. The only caution I would have it to think hard about how you might want to change things down the road. Changing an API isn't the easiest thing to do, but introducing a new content type and deprecating an older one isn't too tough.

Don't get me wrong, I'm all for standards, but they, by their very nature, are almost *always* behind the real world. Case in point, the RCF doesn't seem to handle generic hierarchical collections of things well.